# Removing underline from a part of the link

Tags: html, css, sass, hyperlink

I have some hyperlinks with content before it . Like in picture.

[image]

This is the code I am using .

```
a {


font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: $grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  &:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  &:before {
    content: '\1F847';
    color: $green;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  &:after {
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

I need the arrow that is added as a content to not have underline as a text decoration but the text needs to keep it . As you can see , i tried to add `text-underline:none` to both before and after , but it didn't work. I can use JS/Query if needed , but still have no idea how to do this .

Comment: Could you share jsfiddle link?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/p2hjgomf/#&togetherjs=Fv7gAcsFAn

Comment: First time using this fiddle .. hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `:before` pseudo element so that it displays as an `inline-block`:

```
  &:before {
    content: '\1F847';
    color: $green;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works but it solved my problem ! Thanks !

Comment: Here's why it works: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#propdef-text-decoration In summary - `text-decoration` will propagage to the likes of the `:before` and `:after`, but not to anything that is `inline-block`.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `text-decoration: none` to the `a`, but insert a span into it with the link text inside the span - then put `text-decoration: underline` of the `a span`. Notethat I had to rejig your css a little since we don't have a preprocessor.

```css
a {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
  
a span {
  text-decoration: underline;
  }
  
 a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

 a:before {
    content: '\1F847';
    color: green;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
```

```html
    <a href="#"><span>2015 Highlights</span></a>
```

Comment: Giving you a vote since it's the other alternative I considered posting. Part of me would prefer your approach, actually.

Comment: Thanks @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ - I upvoted yours too because I learned something from it - thanks.

Comment: Thanks for advice ! Not a bad idea :)

Comment: I prefer avoiding pseudo elements if possible. Makes the code easier to maintain. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @JonasPraem Easier to maintain is subjective. I would agree this should be the accepted answer _if_ the OP was asking about approach - but he is asking specifically about the CSS targetting mark-up that is already in place. It's not uncommon for developers to need to work around mark-up that is being rendered by some third-party. I, too, prefer to avoid pseudo-elements. Anything that is 'magic' and hidden I'm not a fan of.